# Synonyms without adding them to the database or aliases for the whole script

Tags: sql, sql-server, alias, synonym

I'm writing one long script to migrate data between databases and I've been told I can't use synonyms, as they are global and can mess with other scripts. I'm told to use fully qualifying table names or aliases or something other than synonyms. But I think there must be a better way.

Is there a way to use what can be effectively called "synonyms", but without actually creating real synonyms? Or to create synonyms local to my script only? Or is there a way to extend the scope of table name aliases to the entire script so I don't still have to write them in every insert/select?

This is all to turn the long table names some of which reach 70 characters to something short like 3-6 characters to greatly improve the script's readability.

Answer (score 0):

[Synonyms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-synonym-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) are not global but part of a schema. They point to four-part names, for server-database-schema-object. So you can create a new database, just for your script, and create the synonyms there:

```
create database MyScriptDb;
create synonym tbl1 for realdb.dbo.VeryLongTableName;
```

As long as no other script use `MyScryptDb`, it's hard to see how they could be impacted.

Comment: I think creating a new database just to use synonyms is going to be met with that "Do you not realize this is even worse?" look in the eyes of my boss :p

Comment: What about a new schema in you existing database?

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

One possibility would be to create synonyms at the beginning of the script and then remove them on all exit paths.  Perhaps this still isn't allowed by the rules.

However, I don't advise doing this.  Objects have names for a reason.  If you rename them in a script, then all of sudden, your script is different from other scripts -- a maintenance problem.

Instead, I would advise you to come up with standard abbreviations for the tables (I would use something related to the first letter of each word in the table name).  In every query where you reference the tables, use the table alias.  Then, start to change all other scripts to use the same aliases.

Don't gratuitously make your script different from the others.  They are all part of the same system and should be using the same conventions for maintainability over time.

Comment: Yea I agree with keeping the convention the same for all scripts, but if there is a better way than writing full table names in each query and aliasing it there, I would love to introduce it and rewrite all other scripts, and even make a nice documentation page about it. Nobody here is against something better, if it is actually better.

Comment: @user1306322 . . . In that case, you can make *global* synonyms and start the work of rewriting other scripts.